# Win32 error: Object has no attribute 'folders'

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32

I'm getting an error whit Outlook .folders with Win32 using python.

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.folders("X").folders("X").folders("X")
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "X", line 34, in 
>       inbox = outlook.folders("X").folders("X").folders("X")
>     File "C:\X\X\X\X\X\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\win32com\client__init__.py", line 473, in **getattr**
>       raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (repr(self), attr))
>   AttributeError: '' object has no attribute 'folders'

It is strange because the script works sometimes on my machine and seems to work with no issues on my collegues machines.

I'm running:

- Python 3.8.1
- pywin32 227

**UPDATE: I noticed I'm able to run the script once when I restart my computer. The error shows up on the second attempt.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script in the error message does not match the script you posted above. Error message:

inbox = **accounts**.folders("X").folders("X").folders("X")

your script:

inbox = **outlook**.folders("X").folders("X").folders("X")

Also, try to use `Folders.Item` function rather than relying on the default property:

inbox = **outlook**.folders.Item("X").folders.Item("X").folders.Item("X")

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I tried a bunch of things and forgot to revert before posting! I updated the error message.

Comment: Try to break that statement into multiple statements - you will get an error if one of the folders does not exist. Keep in mind that the top level folders are really store names (e.g. "user@domain.com")

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried every folders individually, but I'm blocked at: object has no attribute 'folders'

Comment: Try to replace Folders with Folder.Item("X")

Comment: It works! Do you know why it worked intermittently without "item"?

Comment: Looks like default properties (e.g. Folders["X"] don't work to well in Python) and require to explicitly specify the function (Folders.Item("X"))